# Custom uploader in Ui component not working

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent

```
   <item name="blutbildhochla" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">
        Magento_Ui/js/form/element/file-uploader
    </item>
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">400
    </item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="additionalClasses"
              xsi:type="string">blutbildhochla
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">
            Magento_Ui/form/field
        </item>
        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">
            Magento_Ui/form/element/uploader
        </item>
        <item name="preview" xsi:type="string">
            Magento_Ui/form/element/preview
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Upload</item>
        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
        <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="wizard/index/upload"/>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

I've added a custom uploader for frontend but once added the component, field was not rendering and the Controller was not hitting.